# how to show different content on txt format using nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I need to full out the difference from two different text file on the internet. I tried look at the answer and all of the answer direct me to nokogiri.

Any solution on how to pull out the data difference using nokogiri in ruby? or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: This question is unanswerable as it stands. You state the input is two text files. What do you want as the output? Why would you use Nokogiri if you have text files, given that Nokogiri is an XML/HTML processor, has nothing to do with text files nor diffing? You should include in your question an example of input, an output you expect for that input, at minimum.

Comment: Give an example of what you have and the expected output.

Comment: Unix-only simplest solution: `\`diff -q <(echo #{open(uri1)}) <(echo #{open(uri2)})\``. It will download files, compare them, and print out the difference only. Note the backticks around.

Comment: Text files? Nokogiri doesn't do text files. Nokogiri is a XML/HTML parser so if you need to read and parse the files into a DOM then that's the tool. There's a big difference between looking at two text files and comparing their contents and comparing two XML or HTML files and looking for differences. The idea of what is a significant difference can be very different with text vs. XML/HTML.

Comment: @mudasobwa. using diff to compare HTML files isn't a valid test as two different HTML or XML files can yield the same content after being rendered by the browser or parsed. Using Nokogiri implies they're XML or HTML but the  question doesn't tell us anything useful. The OP has to describe the problem better.

Comment: @Amadan thanks for pointing that out. Obviously nokogiri not the solution here since its in text format. I got 2 different file in txt format in which i need to compare it from the internet. The output that I need to get from those two files is only the difference from those file that I compare. What has been added or deleted from those two files.

Comment: @theTinMan “I need to full out the difference from two different text file on the internet”: *text files*.

Comment: @mudasobwa, the OP wants the "data difference" using Nokogiri. That strongly implies a need to find differences in content, not in characters. `diff` is excellent when comparing bytes and characters but it has no knowledge of how HTML or XML represent data and will report false-positives if the markup differs in structure but not in content. That the files are text is a given since both HTML and XML are text by definition and comparing them at a character level is easy. Comparing the data is an entirely different and much more difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff-lcs` gem.

```
require 'diff/lcs'
require 'open-uri'
text1 = URI.parse('http://www.example.org/text1.txt').read
text2 = URI.parse('http://www.example.org/text2.txt').read
diff = Diff::LCS.diff(text1, text2)
```

Unfortunately, as you declined to provide an example of output even after several people asked you about it, I can't say much more than this.

Comment: sorry @Amadan I am trying to put the example code in here so it will be more clear to you. But for some reason it won't let me add comment again saying I don't have enough reputation by adding the code review. I am a newbie here trying to play around with this 

i found out the answer and it works. 
[https://github.com/samg/diffy]
Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure you can edit posts, even [at your reputation of 1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts): "If other users ask you for more information in the comments, edit your question using the edit link just below your original question."

Comment: @ror, finish the Stack Overflow tutorials and you'll have plenty of points to comment, edit and start helping others. The tutorials are there to teach you the rules and give you a feel for how the site works. Jumping in to ask a question without having done them does you a disservice, so please take the time to finish the introduction to SO.